# Sticky posts are only displayed correctly on first page

Tags: css, wordpress, posts, sticky

I have 2 loops to display the sticky posts (loop 1) and all posts (loop 2). The sticky posts are styled differently than the posts of loop 2. Now I added `posts_nav_link();` to my code to show only 6 of the posts of loop 2 per page. The navigation works but when I navigate the sticky posts are only styled correctly on the very first page.

I styled the sticky posts like this:

HTML:

```
<?php // div class for styling sticky posts. ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>          
    <?php the_excerpt(); // Show summary of posts only. ?>

</div> <!-- end class sticky -->
```

CSS:

```
.sticky {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML (with firebug) on the first page:

```
<div class="blogpost">
<div id="post-324" class="post-324 post type-post status-publish format-standard sticky hentry category-uncategorized">
<h2>
<a title="This is a sticky post" href="http://mywebsite.com/?p=324">This is a sticky post</a>
</h2>
<p>
Written on 10/08/2012. Filed under
<a rel="category" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" href="http://mywebsite.com/?cat=1">Uncategorized</a>
.
</p>
<p>
Content of the post.
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/?p=324">[Read more ...]</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

HTML (with firebug) on all the other pages:
(It looks the same to me.)

```
<div class="blogpost">
<div id="post-324" class="post-324 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<h2>
<a title="This is a sticky post" href="http://mywebsite.com/?p=324">This is a sticky post</a>
</h2>
<p>
Written on 10/08/2012. Filed under
<a rel="category" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" href="http://mywebsite.com/?cat=1">Uncategorized</a>
.
</p>
<p>
Content of the post.
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/?p=324">[Read more ...]</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can display the posts with their own CSS on each page when navigating?

Comment: what does the html that wordpress is giving you once you click to the second page look like?

Comment: Missing stylesheet or more global selector lacking maybe? Select the div with class `blogpost` in firebug and look at the breadcrumb in both pages. Is it the same? And do you have the same CSS files in the CSS tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "sticky class only appears in the front page. 
You can see that on your second html your div with the  ID of "post-324" didnt render the class. You can add the class of sticky also manually by putting:

```
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('class-name'); ?>>
```

so your code should look like this:

```
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('sticky'); ?>>
```

I haven't tried it but it should work according to the wordpress codex.

I hope it works out.